# lattice legend's text position and aligment

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am using lattice package from R. The produced plot has legends, and I want to change the text position of these legends rather than the default (which is always left) to the right position. Example:

[image]

As you can see, "Before" the legends produced by lattice like this, whcih I would like to make them like "After".

My trying code:

```
print(barchart(Value~Topic|Project, d2, groups=Variable, origin=0,
    main="Title", auto.key=list(corner = c(0.99, 0.99),points=TRUE,
    rectangles=FALSE, background = "gray97" , 
    title="Legends",  cex=0.8, cex.title=1), xlab="topics",
    ylab=expression(paste("Cose(", theta, ")"))) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `key` to construct your legend in the order you want.  Here is an example drawing the `points` column before the `text` column:

```
library(lattice)
data(Cars93,package="MASS")

labels=levels(Cars93$Cylinders)
xyplot(Price~EngineSize,groups=Cylinders,data=Cars93,
 key=list(space="right",adj=0,title="Legends",
          points=list(pch=1,
                  col=trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")$col[1:length(labels)]),
          text=list(labels))
)
```

Comment: How could I make the changes on auto.key directly from the barchart, rather than doing it in a separate key.

Comment: I got error `Error in fun(key = quote(list(space = "right", adj = 0, title = "Legends",  : 
  first component of text must be vector of labels`
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide your data and the actual code you are trying.

Comment: I used ggplot2 instead and it solved the problem. thank you